# Create a row in DataGridView using a SQL database table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an SQL Server Running and i want to create a row based on the SQL table rows I have but I don't know how to do that.

All I want is the program to search for the row id and then paste the data in the table.

Can somebody help me?

```
Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(????)
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Load data from database to `DataTable` object, 2. Bind datatabse to `DataGridView`: `MyDataGridView.DataSource = loadedDataTable`

Comment: There would be examples of displaying data from a database in a `DataGridView` all over the web so the fact that you seem to have no idea at all what to do indicates that you have tried to find out. It's your responsibility to do everything you can for yourself before posting here, which includes searching the web and making an effort to implement what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't give a whole ot of information about your setup, but I think you want something like this (generic example of how to insert data into a SQL Server table).

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim sql As String
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        sql = "insert into product (Product_id,Product_name,Product_price) values(7,'Product7',700)"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Row inserted !! ")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```